# How to create routes for 2 types of users accessing the same resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been banging my head over the past few days trying to model this. I have 2 types of users: `doctors` and `hospitals`. Hospitals can post `cases` and doctors can claim them.

`doctor has_many cases`, `hospital has_many cases`, `cases belong_to doctor` and `cases belong_to hospital`.

Both of them have a `profile`. That's the starting point where they can choose to view the cases they have. Hospitals can only see the cases they posted. Doctors can only see all unclaimed cases and the cases they are currently reviewing.

How do I design my routes to "make sense" RESTfully?

Here is my proposed routes.rb:

```
resource :doctor_profile, only: :show do            #=> Show doctor profile
    resources :cases, only: [:index, :show, :edit] #=> See 1 or all cases, edit case
end

resource :hospital_profile, only: :show do
    resources :cases, only: [:create, :index, :show, :edit]
end
```

A few more questions:

1. Do they share controllers? I'm just assuming that they have their own controllers.
2. How do I get them to share the same route but show different things? Ex: "profile/cases" when accessed by a doctor = see their plates, and "profile/cases" when accessed by a hospital = see their plates.
3. Do I even create a `cases_controller`?
4. Is CanCan a good use case for this?

This is honestly feeling like 2 apps accessing 1 database. Is it supposed to be like this? (I think this is parallel to e-commerce where a buyer sees things differently from a seller). So any recommended resources are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally what I would do in this scenario is create this controller structure

```
/app/controllers/doctors_controller.rb
/app/controllers/doctors/cases_controller.rb

/app/controllers/hospitals_controller.rb
/app/controllers/hospitals/cases_controller.rb
```

Then, for each directory of nesting, you need to wrap the controller in a module. For example in `doctors/cases_controller.rb`

```
module Doctors
  class CasesController < ApplicationController

  end
end
```

Now you can create your `routes.rb`

```
resources :doctors do 
  resources :cases, controller: 'doctors/cases', only: [:index, :show] do 
    post '/claim', action: 'claim'
  end
end
```

You also might consider adding a root-level controller for cases that handles the basic functions, which the two nested `cases_controller`s inherit from. This is the place I like to put authorization methods that apply to both controllers

```
# app/controller/cases_controller.rb
class CasesController < ApplicationController

end
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, @Brian. Do you have resources on how you came across with the answer? I was looking at Spree and they actually created  `frontend` and `backend` Rails apps for buyers/sellers. How would you reconcile the views? Do they have their own namespaced folders too?

Comment: views go in the same folder structure, models can chill where they are, or you can nest them

Comment: I wish I had better sources on how I got this. It's really just a feature of the ruby language combined with rails' intelligent namespace design. Trial and error I guess...

Comment: Oks. Last question, if it's not too much. How would the doctors/hospitals share routes? Something like `profile/cases` for both, where doctors can access their own cases only, and hospitals can access their own cases only too

Comment: That would be what you would use the root-level `cases_controller` for. create an index action that detects whether to show all cases for the current user.