# How can I map different controllers to 1 route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app has two users, `doctors` and `hospitals`. Doctors can view cases and diagnose them, and hospitals create cases for the doctors to diagnose. This is all done from their own user profiles.

The way the routes are set up is this: doctor_profile_path: go to doctor's profile. hospital_profile_path: go to a hospital's profile.

I want `profile_path` to redirect to a User's profile, regardless of what account they have. That way they also can't go to the `doctor_profile_path` when they are a hospital, and the path names are more concise. How do I do this?

Other questions:

1. How do I implement authorizations?
2. How should the views folder be structured?

> routes.rb. I tried putting path: 'profile' but Rails will just find the first available matcher so it doesn't work

```
  resource :doctor_profile, only: :do do 
    resources :plates, controller: 'doctor/cases', only: [:index, :show] do 
      post '/claim', action: 'claim'
    end
  end

  resource :hospital_profile, only: :do do 
    resources :cases, controller: 'hospital/cases', only: [:new, :create]
  end
```

> Controller structure is like this:

```
doctor/
  -> cases_controller #=> contains the actions a doctor can do with a case
  -> (things the doctor can do on his profile)
hospital
  -> cases_controller #=> contains the actions a hospital can do with a case
  -> (things a hospital can do on his profile)
profile_controller.rb
```

(This is a continuation of [How to create routes for 2 types of users accessing the same resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207282/how-to-create-routes-for-2-types-of-users-accessing-the-same-resource))

Comment: Are you using devise? If so, both doctor and hospital use the same User resource to log in?

Comment: Thanks for answering @rmagnum2002. Yup. Just one authentication for both types of accounts. Should I use two?

Comment: join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49149/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-22223608-how-can-i-map-different-controllers-t

Answer (score 1):

```
def profile 
  @user = current_user 
end
```

in `ProfilesController`

and add in `routes`

```
get '/profile' => 'profiles#profile'
```

that will give you the path: `profile_path` and build a link with it `<%= link_to 'profile', profile_path %>`

now you might want to display different kind of information if `user` is a `doctor` or `hospital`
so in `views/profiles/profile.html.erb` you'll do

```
<%= render partial: "#{@user.is_doctor? ? 'doctor' : 'hospital'}"  %>
```

that will require 2 partials in `app/views/profiles`

```
1 _doctor.html.erb 
2 _hostpital.html.erb
```

---

if you have **user.profile_type** attribute:

```
def is_doctor? 
  self.profile_type == 'doctor'
end
```

Comment: Hey man, I checked this out. What about [Tell Don't Ask](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/tell-dont-ask) though? I feel like we can split the conditionals into polymorphism

Comment: Good page, but it seems that this page says there are better ways to do, not the best, I don't know if there is a way to render 2 different pages in a method if you know what I mean. You could skip completely this if/else statement in profile page if you will not have too many differences in the page and use class methods to tell not to ask :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may need only one user model, but with different roles(doctor/hospital). The followings are where you can start:

- [rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) - to define roles for your user model.
- [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) - to define what can be done by each roles.

both of them can work with an authentication framework, such as [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

**UPDATE:**

I already answer some association concepts in the chat. Here I just provide an example to solve your problem in my opinion.

You don't need "two" kinds of user models, instead, use one single user model with different roles, then everything becomes simple. All you need is to handle the user, for example, a single user login page and a single user profile page, and show different parts according to the user's role if needed. Here is an example:

You may need add a `role` column in the user model to tell which role a user is(here I just want to simplify the example), and add some methods for the role control.(see the user model below). Note that you should assign a role when a user is created.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      # ...
      # NOTE: here is a simple example to implement a single role
      #       management(i.e., one role only for each users), if you
      #       need more complex management, please consider using
      #       a role management gem, such as rolify.
      # role: 0 = normal user, 1 = doctor, 2 = hosiptal
      t.integer :role, null: false, default: 0
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

But how about the particular fields for doctor and hospital? I would create another two models - `DoctorInfo` and `HospitalInfo` to store these fields for different roles, and make an association(belongs to) the user model. A user has one `doctor_info` if his/her role is a doctor, has one `hospital_info` if his/her role is a hospital.

```
class CreateDoctorInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:doctor_infos) do |t|
      # ...
      t.belongs_to :user
      # ...
      # columns for a doctor role only
      # ...
    end
  end
end

class CreateHospitalInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:hospital_infos) do |t|
      # ...
      t.belongs_to :user
      # ...
      # columns for a hospital role only
      # ...
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one: hospital_info
  has_one: doctor_info
  # ...

  ROLE_MAP = {
    normal_user: 0,
    doctor: 1,
    hospital: 2
  }

  validates :role, inclusion: { in: ROLE_MAP.values }

  def is_a_role?(role_code)
    (self.role == ROLE_MAP[role_code])
  end
end

class DoctorInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: user
  # ...
end

class HospitalInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: user
  # ...
end
```

If you want to show particular fields according the role in your user profile view, the simplest way is just as rmagnum2002 mentioned in his answer.

```
<div>
  To show the profiles for all kinds of roles.
</div>

<% @user.is_a_role?(:doctor) %>
  <div>
    To show the particular information for a user who is a doctor.
    You may need something like this: @user.doctor_info.xxx
  </div>
<% end %>

<% @user.is_a_role?(:hospital) %>
  <div>
    To show the particular information for a user who is a hospital.
    You may need something like this: @user.hospital_info.xxx
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How about the "Tell Don't Ask"? Again, depend on your requirement. Is the role behavior so different between each roles and need a polymorphism(what I mean is a pure ruby class polymorphism, not a model polymorphism. Note that the role behavior is a code-level implementation, there is nothing about the data.) to handle them? or just only a display difference in some pages? It's actually another story.

Comment: Thanks @Sibevin. What if I went with 2 user models though? I went with polymorphic association for this cause there are fields that doctors have that hospitals don't and vice-versa

Comment: If they are so different that you need two models to handle them, I think they should be independent and have their own controllers and views(such as separated login/profile pages). It's really a uncommon case, the only use case I have seen is for users and admins.

Comment: If there are only few different fields between doctor/hospital models, I still suggest using one user model with roles, but add two additional models, for example, doctor_info and hospital_info. The different fields are stored in these two models and these models are associated with(belongs_to) the user model. A user has one doctor_info if the role is a doctor and has one hospital_info if the role is a hospital.

Comment: That is a bit similar to what I did,  but in my case it was: `User belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true`, `Doctor has_one :user`, `Hospital has_one :user`. What do you think?

Comment: I am getting confused with your case... If a user need email and password to login, which model are the email and password columns in? In user, doctor, hospital, or both doctor and hospital?

Comment: They are in user. Should it be reversed? `user has doctor_info` as opposed to `doctor has user`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49253/discussion-between-sibevin-wang-and-daryll-santos)